# Zipper: "cierre" vs "cremallera"

Tags: vocabulario, méxico, sinónimos, dialectos, hispanoamérica

Both mean *zipper* but which one is prevalent in regular speech? Is there any subtle difference between the words as in the type of zipper they refer to? I am particularly interested in Mexican usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cierre is an easier, lazier way to refer to zipper.  It literally means close; a conjugation of to close.

Cremallera is actually a zipper, the mechanism use to join openings in fabrics.

Comment: Is that the regular Mexican usage?

Comment: Seeing as `cierre` is easier to say than `cremallera`, I'd assume it's pretty universal.  Cremallera sounds more formal.. as in, the word used in the zipper industry.

Answer (score 6):

In Spain is much more common to hear `cremallera`. You could use `cierre` and people would still understand you, provided that there is enough context

> Se me ha enganchado el cierre.

Actually, the definition of `cremallera` is

> el **cierre** que se aplica a una abertura longitudinal cierre en prendas de vestir o bolsos.

which implies that other pieces of clothing without a zipper can be said to have a "cierre", which may consist in buttons, velcro or other things. Actually it seems that in some places, like Argentina, Perú and Uruguay the `cremallera` is known as **cierre relámpago**.

According to [wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cremallera_%28indumentaria%29) the zipper is known as

- `Cremallera` in Spain and Colombia
- `Cierre` (or *cierre relámpago*) in Paraguay, Argentina, Ecuador, **Mexico**, Bolivia, Chile, Colombia, Perú, Venezuela and Uruguay
- `Zíper` or zipper in Puerto Rico, Costa Rica, Cuba, El Salvador, Guatemala, Honduras Nicaragua, Panamá and Dominican Republic